# How to cache using Pyramid?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've looked in the documentation and haven't seen (from first sight) anything about cache in Pyramid. Maybe I missed something... Or maybe there are some third party packages to help with this.

For example, how to cache db query (SQLAlchemy), how to cache views? Could anyone give some link to examples or documentation?

Appreciate any help!

**EDITED:**

How to use memcache or database type cache or filebased cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should install [pyramid_beaker](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/).

Then read the [beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) documentation. By default it uses memory based cache, but it can easily support memcached and filebased cache.

Answer (score 6):

Your options are pyramid_beaker and dogpile.cache

pyramid_beaker was written to offer beaker caching for sessions.  it also lets you configure beaker cache regions, which can be used elsewhere.

dogpile.cache is a replacement for beaker.  it hasn't been integrated to offer session support or environment.ini based setup yet.  however it addresses a lot of miscellaneous issues and shortcomings with beaker.

you can't/shouldn't cache a SqlAlchemy query or results. weird and bad things will happen, because the SqlAlchemy objects are bound to a database session.  it's much better to convert the sqlalchemy results into another object/dict and cache those.